# How to define initialized C-array in the Pyrex?

Tags: python, c, python-c-extension, pyrex

I want to define initialized C-array in Pyrex, e.g. equivalent of:

```
unsigned char a[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

What will be equivalent in Pyrex?

Just array is

```
cdef unsigned char a[8]
```

But how can I made it initialized with my values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Cython](http://www.cython.org/), Pyrex's successor, this feature was added over a year a go to fix this [feature request](http://trac.cython.org/cython_trac/ticket/93), so for example the following works in Cython now:

```
cdef double a[] = [0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1]
```

However, Pyrex's development is proceeding much more slowly (which is why Cython was forked years ago by developers rarin' for faster action), so I doubt it's picked up this feature (though you can try, esp. if you're using the [very latest release](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/Pyrex-0.9.8.6.tar.gz) of Pyrex, 0.9.8.6).

If Pyrex isn't giving you the features you want, may I suggest switching to Cython instead?  Most Pyrex code should just recompile smoothly in Cython, and you do get the extra features this way.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I can't use Cython because it supports only gcc, at least when I've checked it last time. I need compatibility with MSVC too.

Comment: @bialix, recent fixes should allow Cython to work around msvc's limitations, though not all made it into 0.12.1 -- if you use mercurial to get http://hg.cython.org/cython-devel/ you could check if it works w/the specific release of msvc (and otherwise open a bug).  BTW, it does work fine w/mingw32, which is link-compatible with msvc and therefore standard CPython windows versions.

Comment: The syntax has changed to `cdef double *a = [0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1]`